# MYSQL how to select all related values in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have a table like below:

[image]

AllowToView has inheritance. For example:

If I would like to search the AllowToView from RoleID 1, Here's the expected output:

[image]

Here's the ideal pseudo code

```
Loop through the table till the end
Select AllowToView, roleID where AllowToView = RoleID
```

And I am thinking of using a while loop or cursor to do that.

```
CREATE temporary TABLE resultTable
(
    ID int(10) NOT NULL
);

insert into reusltTable select AllowToView from tbl where RoleID = 1;
insert into reusltTable select AllowToView from tbl where RoleID = (select AllowToView from tbl where RoleID = 1);
```

Here's the current SQL I'm using, but it cause a problem:

it only selects 2 and 3 (Maximum 2 layers of inheritance), but if there are more records in the table / more inheritance, not all records will be shown.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you investigated the use of recursive CTEs?

Comment: @corky_bantam can i have an example of that??

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx